# Question about Dirichlet Series Related to Formula for $\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, mobius-function, mellin-transform

This question is related to the three functions defined in (1) to (3) below where $\coth(z)$ gives the hyperbolic cotangent of $z$.

---

**(1)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\mu(n)\quad\text{(Mertens function)}$

**(2)** $\quad\frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)\,\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\,,\quad M(N)=0\land N\to\infty$

**(3)** $\quad f(s)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)\,\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\,n^{-s}\,,\quad N\to\infty$

---

The following three figures illustrate the error in formula (2) for $\frac{1}{e}$ as a function of the upper evaluation limit $N$. The red discrete portions of the figures illustrate the error in formula (2) when $M(N)=0$. Formula (2) converges fairly rapidly (when $M(N)=0$), e.g. the error in formula (2) evaluated at $N=39$ is approximately $-2.343\times 10^{-18}$.

---

[image: Error in Formula (2) for N<=100]

**Figure (1)**: Error in Formula (2) for $\frac{1}{e}$ for $1\le N\le 100$

---

[image: Error in Formula (2) for N<=1000]

**Figure (2)**: Error in Formula (2) for $\frac{1}{e}$ for $1\le N\le 1000$

---

[image: Error in Formula (2) for N<=10000]

**Figure (3)**: Error in Formula (2) for $\frac{1}{e}$ for $1\le N\le 10000$

---

The following figure illustrates a discrete plot of $\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ (related to formulas (2) and (3) above) which converges fairly rapidly to $1$ as $n\to\infty$ which explains why the evaluation of formula (2) for $\frac{1}{e}$ changes very little between successive values of $N$ for which $M(N)=0$ as $N\to\infty$.

---

[image: coth(n/2)]

**Figure (4)**: $\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$

---

The following three figures illustrate the absolute value, real, and imaginary parts of formula (3) for $f(s)$ evaluated along the critical line ($s=1/2+i\,t$) using an upper evaluation limit of $N=10,000$.  The red discrete portions of the three figures below illustrate the evaluation of formula (3) at the first $10$ non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper-half plane.

---

[image: Evaluation of Absolute Value of Formula (3)]

**Figure (5)**: Evaluation of $\left|f\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,t\right)\right|$

---

[image: Evaluation of Real Part of Formula (3)]

**Figure (6)**: Evaluation of $\Re\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,t\right)\right)$

---

[image: Evaluation of Imaginary Part of Formula (3)]

**Figure (7)**: Evaluation of $\Im\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,t\right)\right)$

---

**Question (1)**: What is the Dirichlet transform of $a(n)=\mu(n)\,\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$? In particular, can $f(s)$ defined in formula (3) above be expressed in closed-form in terms of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: $f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) e^{-nt}$ then $2i \pi f(t+a) = \int_{(c)} \Gamma(s)\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} (t+a)^{-s}ds$ it is clear (when $2i \pi a \in \Bbb{Q}$) it as well as $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(t+am)$ won't be directly related to the theory of $\zeta(s)$. For the convergence rate of your series for $1/e$ make clear the coefficients of the partial sums (series in $e^{-n}$) and see what bound you obtain for the remainder.

Comment: @reuns I'm not quite following you as $\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)=\frac{e^{n/2}+e^{-n/2}}{e^{n/2}-e^{-n/2}}=\frac{e^n+1}{e^n-1}$. I know $\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ is approximated by the asymptotic $1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k\,t}$ and less precisely by $1+2\,e^{-t}$ (which only includes the first term of the sum over $k$), but $f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\coth\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\,\theta(x-n)$ is not the same thing as $f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\,e^{-n\,t}$.

Comment: In my comment above, $\theta(x-n)$ should have been $\theta(t-n)$.

Comment: Your Dirichlet series is the Mellin transform of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) \coth(n/2)e^{-nt}$